# Python module structure for classes

Tags: python, class, module

I'm currently working on a project that I am structuring in the following manner:

```
.
├── example_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── classes
│       ├── ExampleClass1.py
│       ├── ExampleClass2.py
│       ├── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── test_app.py
```

Inside of `classes/__init__.py` I have defined a base class for all of the other "ExampleClasses" to inherit from. Then, inside of `app.py` I need to import all of these classes. However, this becomes very verbose, as I have to type:

```
from example_app.classes.ExampleClass1 import ExampleClass1
from example_app.classes.ExampleClass2 import ExampleClass2
...
```

Is there a way to structure this in a better way? Ideally I would like to keep each class in a separate file as they are not really similar to each other. I thought of importing all the classes inside of `classes/__init.py` but that does not seem right.

Note that although I only pictured 2 example classes there could be several (tens) of them so importing by hand is quite cumbersome and brittle.

Comment: Your modules (`ExampleClass*.py`) has the classes of the same names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, importing all the classes you want to expose from the subpackage `classes` inside its `__init__.py` is the way to go. In fact, that's what many top-tier Python libraries/frameworks do (see TensorFlow/Keras `layers` subpackage [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py) and Python's `multiprocessing` subpackage [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py)).

When doing that, however, you should probably follow [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) and:

> Use import statements for packages and modules only, not for
> individual classes or functions. Note that there is an explicit
> exemption for imports from the typing module.

In your case, it would translate to this:

`example_app/classes/__init__.py`:

```
from example_app.classes.ExampleClass1 import ExampleClass1
from example_app.classes.ExampleClass2 import ExampleClass2
```

`example_app/__init__.py`:

```
# ...
from example_app import classes
# ...
```

Some other `.py`:

```
from example_app import classes
ex1_instance = classes.ExampleClass1()
```

Or even better:

```
import example_app as ex
ex1_instance = ex.classes.ExampleClass1()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat a module as a class. If your module `ExampleClassN.py` is only to define a class `ExampleClassN`, just add the following two line at the end of each module.

```
import sys
sys.modules[__name__] = ExampleClassN  # N = 1, 2, ...
```

Then you can

```
from example_app.classes import ExampleClass1
from example_app.classes import ExampleClass2
...
```

or

```
from example_app.classes import (
    ExampleClass1,
    ExampleClass2,
    ...
)
```

or

```
from example_app.classes import *
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `__init__.py` shouldn't contain your base class. It is better to have separate file for the base class, as `__init__.py` usually serves as initializaion of the module.

What you can do is following:

- use `__init__.py` to import all of the  classes from the submodules. Eg.

  ```
    import ExampleClass1.ExampleClass1
    import ExampleClass2.ExampleClass2

    __all__ = ['ExampleClass1','ExampleClass2']
  ```

Finally in order to use the wildcard operator, e.g. `from classes import *` you need to add the following line

`__all__ = ['ExampleClass1','ExampleClass2']`